# jQuery email validation issue

Tags: jquery

I found a jquery email validation which works fine on its own. I have now added it to other functions to validate checkboxes and empty fields. full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/vUAGs/4/

```
     function validateEmail(email) {
      var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
      if( !emailReg.test( email ) ) {
        add_color(email, 'orange');
        return false;
      } else {
        add_color(email, white);
        return true;
      }
    }
```

The form still return not valid even though the email is valid.

Comment: Do you have an example of it working fine on its own?

Comment: Well the one I have posted above it works, however I must be doing something wrong when I check if all the fields validate (return true)...

Comment: there is no jQuery code involved in validating the email address.

Comment: there is jQuery involved in the all form validation process

Comment: I don't know how technology you're using, but, why can't you use <input type="email" required />? Just a suggest. Hugs!

Comment: Does IE ring a bell to you?

Comment: `\w-\.` is not a valid range. Try `\w.-` Also, there are a lot more characters allowed in an email address than `\w` covers, your regex is insufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes on your fiddle, and now it works....you can refine the code ;)

HTML:

```
<input class="email_val" type="email" id="emailin" value=""/>
```

JS:

```
function validate_form(){

        $('form input:not(.checkbox_wrapper input, .email_val), textarea').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                add_color($(this), red);
            }
            else {
                add_color($(this), white);
            }

        });
       var emailin = $('#emailin').val();
       return (validateEmail(emailin) && check_Radio_Checkb() && true);

    }


 function validateEmail(emailin) {

         var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  alert(regex.test(emailin));

      if( !regex.test( emailin ) ) {
        add_color(email, 'orange');

        return false;
      } else {
        add_color(email, white);

          return true;
      }

    }
```

See the worrking fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/vUAGs/9/

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a jQuery object to validateEmail, rather than an email address.

```
function validate_form(){

        $('form input:not(.checkbox_wrapper input, .email_val), textarea').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                add_color($(this), red);
            }
            else {
                add_color($(this), white);
            }

        });
                    //              V right here
        return (!validateEmail(email.val()) && check_Radio_Checkb() && true); // Notice change here

    }
```

Make that change and it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the input field, you still have to get the value of the input field.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tive/vUcVa/

also you can shorten your function like this when declaring `emailReg` global inside your function scope:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var isValid = emailReg.test(email.val());
    if (!isValid) {
        add_color(email, 'orange');
    } else {
        add_color(email, "green");
    }
    alert(isValid);
    return isValid;
}
```

Make note that the return statement in your `validate_form()` function doesn't need an invert like you did. Reads a bit better ^^